# argument of type double is incompatible with parameter type double pointer

Tags: c++, types, double

Trying to find the lowest score and highest and I keep getting the error

```
argument of type "double" is incompatible with parameter of type "double*"
```

Code:

```
cout << "The lowest of the results = " << find_lowest(score[5]);
cout << "The highest of the results = " << find_highest(score[5]);

system("Pause");


}

double find_highest(double a[])
{
double temp = 0;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    if(a[i]>temp)
        temp=a[i];
}
return temp;
}

double find_lowest(double a[])
{
double temp = 100;
for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
{
    if(a[i]<temp)
        temp=a[i];
}
return temp;
}
```

Comment: Your function expects a `double` array, but you pass it only one `double` element. `score[5]` means "element number 5 of the array named `score`".

Comment: "Thanks for the support" is absolutely meaningless as a question subject, and is worthless for use by future users of this site when searching. Please [edit] to something that is useful and relevant to the content of your question.

Answer (score 1):

As @jogojapan pointed out, you will have to change these

```
  cout << "The lowest of the results = " << find_lowest(score[5]);
  cout << "The highest of the results = " << find_highest(score[5]);
```

to

```
  cout << "The lowest of the results = " << find_lowest(score);
  cout << "The highest of the results = " << find_highest(score);
```

Your functions expect a double array, not a double element.

Answer (score 0):

"double*" is a pointer to a variable of type "double". You've written

```
cout << "The lowest of the results = " << find_lowest(score[5]);
```

and "score[5]" returns the 6th element in the array `score`. You just need

```
cout << "The lowest of the results = " << find_lowest(score);
```

In C and C++ array's can decay to pointers, and do when used as function arguments. find_lowest score expects `double a[]` which decays to `double*`, but you're trying to pass it the 6th element of score which is a `double`, not a `double*`

Answer (score 0):

score[5] is the double at position 5 in the score array (0,1,2,3,4,5).
If you want to send the first 6 elements of the score array you might want to try something like this:

```
find_lowest((int[]){score[0],score[1],score[2],score[3],score[4],score[5]});
```

It may be a better idea to do something like this to make your functions a little more flexible but you'd need to maintain the length of arrays being used (but I guess you're kind of doing that already by assuring that they're 6 elements or more).

```
double find_highest(double a[], size_t len)
{
   double temp = 0;
   for(size_t i=0;i<len;i++)
   {
       if(a[i]>temp)
       temp=a[i];
   }
   return temp;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

The problem is the expression `find_lowest(score[5])`, `score[5]` is of type double whereas in the function's parameter list you have specified `double[]` or `double*` hence the error.

So make the following correction:

```
cout << "The lowest of the results = " << find_lowest(score);
cout << "The highest of the results = " << find_highest(score);
```

Also, there are a few bugs in your `find_highest()` function, if the input array had all negative numbers like a[]={-1.0,-2.0,-3.5,-5.0,-1.3} then your function will `return 0` which is incorrect, the correct implementation would be:

```
double find_highest(double a[])
{
 double temp = a[0];
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  if(a[i]>temp)
     temp=a[i];
 }
 return temp;
}
```

Similarly the `find_lowest()` function should be:

```
double find_lowest(double a[])
{
 double temp = a[0];
 for(int i=0;i<5;i++)
 {
  if(a[i]<temp)
     temp=a[i];
 }
 return temp;
}
```